# VBScript for AD account creation

Tags: vbscript

Does the following code look okay? Want to see if anyone can spot any mistakes I may have made. This will be pulling from a pre-formatted Excel document - I have already specified all needed Cell locations.

Things I want clarified:

- How many times can you invoke SetInfo and did I use it more than needed? I was under the impression that a SetInfo would be needed before a SetPassword can be used, but I could be very wrong.
- Does this line look okay? Was I correct to separate multiple cells using a comma in order to put all the info together? I know it worked with an Echo command:

  ```
  Set objUser = objOU.Create _
  ("User", "cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value, objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value, objExcel.Cells(intRow, 19).Value)
  ```
- Is this the correct code for setting a password to never expire?

  ```
  objUser.Put "userAccountControl", intUAC XOR _
  ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
  ```
- Full code below, I'd appreciate any feedback on anything else that is found.

  ```
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
      ("C:\Book1.xls")
  intRow = 2
  Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
      Set objOU = GetObject _
      ("ou=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 13).Value & _
          ", dc=satdc, dc=com")
      Set objUser = objOU.Create _
          ("User", "cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value, objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value, objExcel.Cells(intRow, 19).Value)
      objUser.sAMAccountName = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 19).Value & ".sat"
      objUser.GivenName = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value
      objUser.SN = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value
      objUser.SetInfo
      objUser.AccountDisabled = False
      objUser.AccountExpirationDate = Date + 365
      objUser.SetPassword objExcel.Cells(intRow, 9).Value
      objUser.SetInfo
      objUser.Put "userAccountControl", intUAC XOR _
          ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
      objUser.HomeDirectory = "\\satdc" & "\" & "Users" & "\" & _
          objUser.Get("sAMAccountName")
      objUser.homeDrive = "U:"
      objUser.SetInfo
      intRow = intRow + 1
  Loop
  objExcel.Quit
  ```

Answer (score 5):

## Naming: *Hungarian Notation* is the DEVIL.

#### It makes the reader want to see your code burn in eternal flames.

> [image]
>
> https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/Flanders_the_Devil

- `objExcel` would be better off as `xlApp` or `excelApp`
- `objUser` is dying to call itself something like `adUser`
- `intRow` wants to be called `xlRow` or just `row`
- `intUAC` is silently begging for a more descriptive name
- `objOU` wants to shoot whoever named it that

Now, whether your code is correct or not is off-topic for this site; since this question hasn't been closed as off-topic yet, I'm going to assume you've got working code.

```
Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
```

I'd use `vbNullString` here instead of `""`. It makes the intent clearer, and the non-string takes up 0 bytes. `""` eats 6 bytes for no reason - `StrPtr(vbNullString)` is 0; `StrPtr("")` is a non-zero memory address.

The repeated assignments on `objUser` are a missed opportunity of using a `With` block:

```
With objOU.Create("User", "cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value, _
                          objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value, _
                          objExcel.Cells(intRow, 19).Value)

    .SAMAccountName = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 19).Value & ".sat"
    .GivenName = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value
    .SN = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value
    .AccountDisabled = False
    .AccountExpirationDate = Date + 365
    '...

End With
```

Your usage of line continuation characters is... well, you use it in weird places. Actually, everywhere you've used it, I wouldn't have. Notice in the above snippet, how I used it to line up the parameters.